# Jquery ajax response error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Here is a partial example of what I am trying to achieve.

I am trying to retrieve a value from ajax but the javascript result.success variable is undefined. I have the following:

PHP:

```
$result = array ("success" => null, "html" => "");
$result['success'] = true;
$result['html'] = "test";
echo json_encode($result);
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var ID = 1
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/load.php',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: 'json',
            data: {ID: ID},
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                        // do something
                }
        });
```

The response I am getting from ajax (retrieved from chrome dev tools) is {"success":true,"html":"Test"}

This looks fine to me however in the JavaScript result.success is undefined. I believe this will be simple I just can't see where the issue lies..

Comment: Try 'result = $.parseJSON(result);' and see if its still undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
datatype: 'json',
```

Javascript is case sensitive and the property is `dataType`:

```
dataType: 'json',
```

Because of that, jQuery is not being told to automatically parse the JSON, so the result is just treated as html or plain text.

You also need to remove the content-type header because that specifies the content type for the request not response. You are sending form/url encoded in the request, not JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I put the content-type header as a recommendation from someone else to fix issue so I have removed that now. The issue was as you expected dataType being lowercase. Again thanks for your constructive response. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/load.php',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {ID: ID},
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj) {
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
            },
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success) {
                        // do something
                }
            } // Maybe your forgot this
        });
```

in other words - Basic Debugging

Comment: WHAT!?!?!  datatype=json and you parse it?

Comment: I missed the } on here but it was in my code looks like my issue was datatype instead of dataType.. :(

Answer (score 0):

in your PHP page put this on top of the page (you are accepting only json response but probably your response headers content type is text/html

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```